# Unusual dependency in deps.json

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC site which has a weird issue with the `deps.json` file, when I generate the files for publication, the resulting `deps.json` file shows a dependency to `"System.Data.OracleClient": "4.0.0.0"`, which isn't referenced anywhere in the code (as far as I know, there's not even a version 4 of `OracleClient`) and I don't know where it got it from.

Now there's nothing wrong with the functionality of the web site, it's working totally fine, but the client won't accept it unless I cut out that reference because that project isn't even connecting to Oracle, in fact, it consumes a web service that connects to a SQL database, so there's no reason for that reference to be there in the first place.

Any help finding out where it comes from and how i can remove it would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

This is the first part of the json file up to the point here the dependency comes up:

```
{
  "runtimeTarget": {
    "name": ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7/win7-x64",
    "signature": "52f6540bd3a1b3a05d465d7fc64e4da473f1d66e"
  },
  "compilationOptions": {
    "defines": [
      "TRACE",
      "RELEASE",
      "NETFRAMEWORK",
      "NET47"
    ],
    "languageVersion": "",
    "platform": "x64",
    "allowUnsafe": false,
    "warningsAsErrors": false,
    "optimize": true,
    "keyFile": "Essentta.MarketplaceKey.pfx",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "xmlDoc": false,
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
  "targets": {
    ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7": {
      "PROMPERU.HablaQuechua.Web.CMS/1.0.0": {
        "dependencies": {
          "1.3.2.Application.Dto": "1.0.0",
          "1.6.1.CrossCutting.Enumerations": "1.0.0",
          "1.6.2.CrossCutting.Strings": "1.0.0",
          "1.6.3.CrossCutting.Helper": "1.0.0",
          "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "2.7.1",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "2.2.0",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "2.2.0",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "2.2.0",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy": "2.2.8",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy": "2.2.0",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "2.2.0",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "2.2.0",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression": "2.2.0",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "2.2.0",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR": "1.1.0",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client": "1.1.0",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "2.2.0",
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "2.2.4",
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "2.2.4",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "2.2.0",
          "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.1.0",
          "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink": "2.2.0",
          "cloudscribe.Web.Pagination": "2.1.2",
          "Microsoft.CSharp.Reference": "4.0.0.0",
          "mscorlib": "4.0.0.0",
          "System.ComponentModel.Composition": "4.0.0.0",
          "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations": "4.0.0.0",
          "System.Core": "4.0.0.0",
          "System.Data": "4.0.0.0",
          "System.Data.OracleClient": "4.0.0.0",
          .
          .
          .
```

I'm also attaching a screenshot of my dependencies:

[dependencies screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqVbg.png)